# All ViewController Views are Nil in Unit Testing?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

Sorry if this is a beginner question but I'm relatively new to Unit testing and didn't see this asked anywhere.

When I start my unit tests in Swift, I setUp my tests by instantiating my viewController.

My code is set up using MVVM (Model - View - ViewModel).  So when I test some of my viewModel methods, they will update the Views (in the ViewController) in the UI.  The problem is, Xcode keeps crashing and says that the views in the ViewController are nil?  How do I prevent these views from being nil?  Am I doing something wrong?  How do I instantiate the views within the viewController?  I thought this would be automatic.

```
class WeirdFaceTests: XCTestCase {

    var viewController: ViewController?
    var tattooModel: ARModel?
    var tattooViewModel: ARViewModel?
    var mainUIModel: MainUIModel?
    var mainUIViewModel: MainUIViewModel?

    override func setUp() {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.setUp()
        self.viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrimaryViewController") as! ViewController

        self.tattooModel = ARModel(imageName: "blank", tattooType: .new)
        self.tattooViewModel = ARViewModel(tattooModel: tattooModel!, delegate: viewController!)

        self.mainUIModel = MainUIModel()
        self.mainUIViewModel = MainUIViewModel(model: mainUIModel!, delegate: viewController!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the `self.viewController?.loadView()` call in the setUp() method.

The correct code that works without nil views is as follows:

```
class WeirdFaceTests: XCTestCase {

    var viewController: ViewController?
    var tattooModel: ARModel?
    var tattooViewModel: ARViewModel?
    var mainUIModel: MainUIModel?
    var mainUIViewModel: MainUIViewModel?

    override func setUp() {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.setUp()
        self.viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrimaryViewController") as! ViewController
        self.viewController?.loadView()
```